# WebCam (easycamera) lenovo yoga pro2 dont work

Tags: upgrade, lenovo, webcam

I have a lenovo lenovo yoga pro 2 with a built-in easycamera that  worked well in 18.04, but with the upgrade to 20.04, it just stop working, disappeared completely.

some lists from my system

lsusb

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 008: ID 04f3:040d Elan Microelectronics Corp. Touchscreen
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 2047:0855 Texas Instruments Invensense Embedded MotionApp HID Sensor
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

lspci

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 0b)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 0b)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Thermal Subsystem (rev 0b)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB xHCI HC (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series HECI #0 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev e4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series SMBus Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series Thermal (rev 04)
01:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 6b)
```

v4l2-ctl --list-devices

```
Dummy video device (0x0000) (platform:v4l2loopback-000):
    /dev/video0
```

has anyone had an identical experience or know what my problem is?